# LaTex how to edit this equation?

Tags: latex, mathematical-expressions

I'm having issues turning this word equation into a LaTex equation. It's coming out looking dodgy, please help!

I added a screen shot of the equation I want, and what I end up getting when I copy and paste into LaTex:

WORD:

[image]

LATEX CODE:

```
\mathrm{=\ }\mathrm{C}_\mathrm{0}\mathrm{[1-}6(Dt)1/2aπ2-3Dta2] + 12(Dt)1/2an = 1∞exp(na(Dt)1/2)
```

and therefore nothing comes out and LaTex doesn't let me run it.

Comment: [TeX.SE] StackExchange is more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

This is absolutely not a proper LaTeX equation code. I don't know what you know about LaTeX, but you cannot just copy and paste from Word or any software to you LaTex editor. Plus, you need to provide your full code for anyone being able to help you.

Anyway, running this MWE should work :

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twoside]{report}
% ===== PACKAGES DECLARATION =====
\usepackage{mathtools}              % Replaces amsmaths + more features
\usepackage{amsfonts}               % Maths fonts package
% ===== DOCUMENT BODY =====
\begin{document}
    \begin{equation} % optional : use the "equation*" environment to remove equation number
        % optional : use traditional math font by removing the \mathrm{} command
        \mathrm{X = C_0 \left[ 1 - \frac{6(Dt)^{1/2}}{a \pi^2} - \frac{3Dt}{a^2}\right] + \frac{12(Dt)^{1/2}}{a} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \exp\left(\frac{na}{(Dt)^{1/2}} \right)}
        % optional : remove auto-sized brackets by removing the \left and \right commands
   \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

As written in the code, you may want to remove the equation number and the big auto-sized brackets (that are more readable in my opinion). Just remove the corresponding commands. Also, you should consider using the "normal" math font and not the roman one that is clearly different from the text and helps the reader to separate equations from inline small expressions you could insert in your document.

Comment: The empty lines in your equation will cause errors

Comment: Interesting, it doesn't give me any errors on my computer.

Comment: Have a look into the .log file, lines 206 and following. There must be a lot of errors.

Comment: Not sure about how to read the .log file, I did not see obvious errors. I'm going to check on this later, I removed the empty lines in my MWE to be sure !

Answer (score 0):

One first sketch:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\[
C_0\left[1-\frac{6(Dt)^{\frac{1}{2}}}{a\pi^2}-\frac{3Dt}{a^2}\right]+%
\frac{12(Dt)^{\frac{1}{2}}}{a}\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}%
\exp\left(\frac{na}{(Dt)^{\frac{1}{2}}}\right)
\]
\end{document}
```

No packages required. The output:

[image: screenshot of output]

Than you can tune the math fonts and anything else.